How to use JSON format equivalent in ChatGroq from langchain_groq?
I am using langchain with the langchain_ollama and langchain_groq integrations to process natural language tasks.
When working with ChatOllama from langchain_ollama, I can use the format="json" parameter like this:
from langchain_ollama import ChatOllama

llm_json_mode = ChatOllama(model=local_llm, temperature=0, format="json")

This ensures that the output is formatted as JSON. However, when using ChatGroq from langchain_groq, I couldn’t find a similar format parameter. Here’s how I currently initialize ChatGroq:
from langchain_groq import ChatGroq

llm_groq_mode = ChatGroq(model=local_llm, temperature=0)

I want the output to be in JSON format, but there doesn't seem to be a format argument for ChatGroq. Is there an equivalent parameter or a way to ensure JSON output when using ChatGroq?
Additional Details
LangChain version:  0.3.10
LangChain_Groq version: 0.2.1
LangChain_Ollama version: 0.2.1
Python version: Python 3.12.0
Any help or guidance would be appreciated!
